# How can I use the jQuery-like selector in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I looking for is:

```
var arrinput = $('input[name$="letter"]')
```

How can I change that from jQuery style to a pure javascript style?

So I want the `<input>` tags which `name` is ended with "letter".

---

I changed code a bit... My browser dont support querySelector and FYI I'm using webbrowser component on c# winforms

Comment: coz I dont want to include jQuery.js to my page :)

Comment: coz I'm in a situation which I prefer not to have a jQuery library.

Comment: Your answer, as well as the answer to "why should I use jQuery instead of doing this myself" is to merge Hemlock's `querySelector` answer with BenjaminHarris's brute-force search so you can fall back if `querySelector` isn't available in your browser. Or, use jQuery which does all this for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    if (/letter$/.test(item.name)) {
        item.value = "A letter";
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost, but `for (item in inputs)` doesn't work that way. `item` will be an index. You need `for (i in inputs) { var item = inputs[i]; ... }` or better yet, `for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) { var item = items[i]; ... }`

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for that. I forgot about that -- I've just been working with Python :D

Comment: if (/letter$/.test(item.name)) <<- what is this mean? I dont understand :(

Comment: `/letter$/.test(item.name)` is a regular expression test for a string ending in `letter`. http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: can I do this? `var temp = "letter"; var re = new RegEx("/" + temp + "$/"); if(re.test(item.name))`

Comment: Theoretically you could. But why would you want to do that? It's a lot more messy (e.g. assigning "letter" to temp -- there's no need for that -- just put "letter" in when you're creating the regex pattern).

Answer (score 15):

For modern browsers:

`document.querySelector('input[name$=letter]');`

will return the first match.

`document.querySelectorAll('input[name$=letter]');`

will return a list of matches.

I suspect that if you look through the jquery source code, it uses `document.querySelector[All]` when it's available.

Comment: too bad my browser not support querySelector :( FYI I use webbrowser component on c# winforms

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post, but I searched a similar solution and I haven't found it.

So I've doing a little function to do that (it's optimizable):

```
/**
 * Searches and finds the parent node for a dom object
 * 
 * @examples: 
 *  getParent(elem, 'div')                  // The first div parent found
 *  getParent(elem, 'div[id]')              // The first div parent with an id found
 *  getParent(elem, 'div[id="toto"]')       // The first div parent with id equals toto found
 *  getParent(elem, 'div[id=^="toto"]')     // The first div parent with id start by toto found
 *  getParent(elem, 'div[id=$="toto"]')      // The first div parent with id end by toto found
 *  getParent(elem, 'div[id=*="toto"]')     // The first div parent with id contains toto found
 *
 * @param domObject elem
 * @param string [target]
 * @return domObject or null
 */
function getParent(elem, target)
{
    if(target == null)
        return elem.parentNode;

    var elem_name = target,
        attr_name = null, attr_value = null, 
        compare_type = null,
        match_val = target.match(/\[.+[^\[\]]\]$/i);

    if(match_val != null) 
    {
        elem_name = elem_name.replace(match_val[0], '');

        var expr = match_val[0].substr(1, match_val[0].length-2),
            tmp = expr.split('=');

        attr_name = tmp[0];
        if(tmp.length == 2) 
        {
            attr_value = tmp[1].toLowerCase();
            attr_value = attr_value.replace(/(\'|\")+/ig, '');

            if(attr_name.match(/\^$/))
                compare_type = 'begin';
            else if(attr_name.match(/\*$/))
                compare_type = 'all';
            else if(attr_name.match(/\$$/))
                compare_type = 'end';
            else
                compare_type = 'simple';

            if(compare_type != 'simple')
                attr_name = attr_name.substr(0, attr_name.length-1);
        }
    }

    var parent = elem.parentNode;

    do 
    {
        if(parent.nodeName.toUpperCase() == elem_name.toUpperCase())
        {
            if(attr_name != null) 
            {
                var attribute = parent.getAttribute(attr_name).toLowerCase();
                if(attribute != null && attribute != '') 
                {
                    if(attr_value == null)
                        return parent;

                    if(compare_type == 'simple' && attribute == attr_value)
                        return parent;
                    if(compare_type == 'begin' && attribute.match(eval('/^'+attr_value+'/ig')))
                        return parent;
                    if(compare_type == 'end' && attribute.match(eval('/'+attr_value+'$/ig')))
                        return parent;
                    if(compare_type == 'all' && attribute.match(eval('/'+attr_value+'/ig')))
                        return parent;
                }
            } else {
                return parent;
            }
        }

        parent = parent.parentNode;
    } 
    while(parent != null);

    return null;
}
```