# Javascripts this.parentElement('div').classList.add Not working

Tags: javascript, addclass

Just almost complete a project and this simple line won't allow me.

```
mykey= document.getElementById('mykey'),

mykey.onclick = function() {this.parentElement('div').classList.add("green")};
```

**On click is not adding class 'green'**

Any thought?

Comment: An elements parentElement isn't a function but a property. You probably want to use a library if you want to find an elements parent using a css selector

Comment: You can try this to find the parent div if you like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410814/how-can-i-use-the-jquery-like-selector-in-pure-javascript#answer-7410870

Comment: I dont want to use lib

Comment: Then check out some of those answers in the post I linked above

Comment: check this one http://jsfiddle.net/8vype/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mykey= document.getElementById('mykey');
mykey.onclick = function() {
    mykey.parentElement.classList.add("green");
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8vype/1/

Answer (score -2):

use following code instead of your one

Its uses jQuery Library and using this will get you to write less code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    mykey= document.getElementById('mykey'),

    mykey.onclick = function() { alert("clicked"); $(this.parentNode).addClass("green")};
});
</script>
```

tested and working,

Edited :

sorry i did not see you comment that you dont want to use lib.