# Using javascript to get sum from input title

Tags: javascript

Below is a javascript which is able to get the input value & needs external libraries.

I know this seem odd but I have to use javascript to grab the price from the input title and **no external libraries is required**. Is it possible to work from input title ?

```
<?php
include_once('database_conn.php');
$sqlCDs = 'SELECT CDID, CDTitle, CDYear, catDesc, CDPrice FROM nmc_cd b inner join nmc_category c on b.catID = c.catID WHERE 1 order by CDTitle';
$rsCDs = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCDs);
while ($CD = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsCDs)) {
    //have a look at the input field below
    echo "\t<div class='item'>
            <span class='CDTitle'>{$CD['CDTitle']}</span>
            <span class='CDYear'>{$CD['CDYear']}</span>
            <span class='catDesc'>{$CD['catDesc']}</span>
            <span class='CDPrice'>{$CD['CDPrice']}</span>
            <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' id="yourId"  name='CD[]' value='{$CD['CDID']}' title='{$CD['CDPrice']}' /></span>
        </div>\n";
}
?>
```

JS:

```
    function isChecked(chosen) {
//and here it is called again
var valOfTitle = document.selectElementById("yourId").getAttribute('title');
   var number = parseFloat(valOfTitle);
    if(chosen.is(':checked')) {
        sum = sum + parseFloat(valOfTitle);
    } else {
        sum = sum - parseFloat(valOfTitle);
    }
    $('#total').valOfTitle(sum.toFixed(2));
};
```

Comment: Post the rendered HTML. Your PHP is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understood you correctly:

you can access the data in your `input` field via jQuery's `attr()` method.

```
// "valOfTitle" is just a name..could also be "george" or "germany"
// "yourInputElementId needs to be the id of your element (written in 
// "")  
var valOfTitle = $(yourInputElementId).attr('title');
```

without jQuery:

```
var valOfTitle = document.selectElementById(yourInputFieldId).getAttribute('title');
```

if you want it as a number you can just do:

```
var number = parseFloat(valOfTitle);
```

if you don't want to add an id to your element you also can use another javascript selector, p.e. `getElementsByName`- but note: this will return a HTML Collection and not a single element, which means you will have to loop over this collection to access your data.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

maybe this google search may help you too:

https://www.google.de/search?q=javascript+selectors&oq=javascript+selectors&aqs=chrome..69i57.4015j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=pure+javascript+selectors

or even

[How can I use the jQuery-like selector in pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410814/how-can-i-use-the-jquery-like-selector-in-pure-javascript)

Comment: so that can output it as a val ?

Comment: I think that jQuery is the "external library" that he is trying to get rid of . . .

Comment: @DoranL yes you can work with `valOfTitle` from here on

Comment: @messerbill really sorry I updated the JS above, but i think i'm not getting something right

Comment: `valOfTitle = document.selectElementById(yourInputFieldId)` - the `yourInputFliedId` needs to be the id of the HTML Element (in your case an input field) you want to extract the attribute. So in your case you have to add in ID to `<input type='checkbox' name='CD[]' value='{$CD['CDID']}' title='{$CD['CDPrice']}' />` to smth like `<input type='checkbox' id="yourId" name='CD[]' value='{$CD['CDID']}' title='{$CD['CDPrice']}' />`

Comment: @messerbill Thank you, but let's say I can't change anything in the while loop echo portion. Can we still do it without id ?

Comment: Can i replace $('#total').valOfTitle(sum.toFixed(2)); with  total.value = valOfTitle(sum.toFixed(2); to avoid external library ?

Comment: `valOfTitle` was just the name for the variable which contains the return value of the JavaScript selector - just like i wrote in my answer. `var valOfTitle = document.selectElementById(yourInputFieldId).getAttribute('title');` this is the line. `yourInputFieldId` here should be the id of your HTML element (with ""). you also could name `valOfTitle` to `jesus` or `pokemon`....these are just names

Answer (score 0):

Just use getAttribute if you dont want to use any external libraries.

```js
element.getAttribute("title")
```